# Redirect All Requests for a Nonexistent File inside directory to the a specific file in the root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect all the 404 errors inside a folder to a file in the root.
i make an example to explain better:
I have a directory www.site.com/join-us/ where I have some files for the positions available: www.site.com/join-us/positon1.php, www.site.com/join-us/positon2.php

from time to time I have to delete some of these positions/files, so I would like to redirect all this 404 errors inside the /join-us/ directory to a specific file www.site.com/join-us.php

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In htaccess in the document root :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/join-us/$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^join-us/(.+)/?$ /join-us.php [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect /join-us/notfountfile to /join-us.php

Comment: thanks, it seems to work partially.
the redirect works, but seems doesn't find the file join-us.php.
I receive this error "Not Found - The requested URL /join-us.php was not found on this server."
maybe is a problem of paths?
I am doing this test on localhost with mamp, I have to specify a something else for the paths? thanks

Comment: @Mattia is the join-us.php file located in root?

Comment: yes, it is in the root. I tried also with another file 404.html but I have the same error

Comment: @Mattia 1.what url are you going to and what exactly happens? 2.Do you any other rules?

Comment: I am sorry, I discovered the problem.
it is not the root, but there is the folder of the current project, like this http://localhost:8888/test-static/join-us.php

I tried to modify your code, like this >     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}//test-static/join-us/$1 !-f  but without success.

Comment: @Mattia if this is not working. remove this from your root htaccess. Create a new htaccess in the `join-us` folder and add the following 3 lines: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !/$ /join-us.php [NC,L]` Or you can also use ErrorDocument `ErrorDocument 404 /join-us.php`